# Android for some reason I have a delay between onPause and onDestroyView

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, lifecycle

I am using an activity with a lot of different fragments in my app, and one main problem I am having is that when I go from one fragment to another there is about a second of delay between onPause and onDestroyView is called(used simple logs to check). This creates a problem that if I press the back button immediately as soon as I enter a fragment it will go back and not call onCreateView, showing basically a blank screen(the activity's background). Any idea what might be causing this to happen? I have been trying to fix this for a long time.

```
class MainMenuTableViewController: Fragment() {

/**Main menu, show all the topics and stuff*/

val Topics = arrayOf<TriviaQuestion.Topic>(TriviaQuestion.Topic.anatomy, TriviaQuestion.Topic.cpr, TriviaQuestion.Topic.medicine, TriviaQuestion.Topic.anamnesis,
        TriviaQuestion.Topic.routine, TriviaQuestion.Topic.trauma, TriviaQuestion.Topic.teamWork, TriviaQuestion.Topic.nbc, TriviaQuestion.Topic.mentalHealth, TriviaQuestion.Topic.publicHealth,
        TriviaQuestion.Topic.other, TriviaQuestion.Topic.coronaTeams, TriviaQuestion.Topic.coronaNursingTeams)
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    DatabaseFacade.fetchTriviaQuestions()
    MenuBarDatabaseFacade.databaseSingleton.getVideosAndMaterials()
    // Handle the back button event
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Log.d("popbackstacktest", "view created")
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    mainMenuTopicsRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    lineImage.scaleX = 0.0000001f
    mainMenuTopicsRecyclerView.adapter = MainMenuTableViewAdapter(Topics) { position ->
        MenuViewController.tabSelected = Tabs.Pdf
        MenuViewController.topicChosen = Topics[position]
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_MainMenuFragment_to_MenuViewFragment)
    }
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Log.d("popbackstacktest", "starting")
}

override fun onResume() {
    Log.d("popbackstacktest", "resuming")
    super.onResume()
    animateLine()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    Log.d("popbackstacktest", "destroying")

}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    Log.d("popbackstacktest", "destroying view")

}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    Log.d("popbackstacktest", "pausing")
}

fun animateLine(){
    /**Animate line to get bigger until full size**/
    lineImage.scaleX = 0.0000001f
    val xScaleAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(lineImage, "scaleX", 1f)
    xScaleAnimator.duration = 1250
    val scaleAnimator = AnimatorSet()
    scaleAnimator.play(xScaleAnimator)
    scaleAnimator.start()
}
```

That is all the code of the fragment, basically it has a recyclerview in it and when I press an item it will navigate to a different fragment accordingly. Problem is that as I have mentioned before, the onDestroyView gets called with a hefty delay even after the other fragment is shown meaning that the onCreateView will not get called if I press the back button immediately after entering the fragment(or if I put popBackStack() in the onViewCreated of the second fragment)

Comment: What version of Fragments are you using?

Comment: @ianhanniballake 1.0.0, will try 2.3.1 a second to see if it changes anything.

Comment: It would be better if you post all of your dependencies as other libraries, such as AppCompat, also pull in fragments as a transitive dependency

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have fragments and fragments navigation, and it seemed to reduce the delay to be almost instant. Looking at common issues in the fragment official page I saw that it had pressing back after going into a fragment may cause a blank screen, so it seems I'll have to wait for the next stable update. Thanks for your help

Comment: No, that's not a known issue with any stable version of Fragments.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thats pretty weird then, when I updated the fragments version the delay shortened drastically. Any idea what it might be then?

Comment: You never included what dependencies you are using, so it is hard to tell what you are using at all.